# Why is "zzz" -le "~~~" false?

Tags: powershell

As the title says, why does this happen?

```
PS C:\temp> "zzz" -le "~~~"
False

PS C:\temp> "~~~" -le "zzz"
True
```

"~" is the next to last ASCII character. I cannot understand a collation where it comes before "z".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: [because it uses `[String]::Compare()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) and that returns the same result.

The longer answer is: it's not an ASCII value compare. It depends on both culture info and comparison options, and the default is to use Word Sort.

> The comparison uses the current culture to obtain culture-specific
>   information such as casing rules and the alphabetic order of
>   individual characters. For example, a culture could specify that
>   certain combinations of characters be treated as a single character,
>   or uppercase and lowercase characters be compared in a particular way,
>   or that the sorting order of a character depends on the characters
>   that precede or follow it.
>
> The comparison is performed using word sort rules. For more
>   information about word, string, and ordinal sorts, see
>   [System.Globalization.CompareOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions(v=vs.110).aspx).

#### Examples

```
[string]::Compare('z','~')  
# 1

[string]::Compare('~','z')  
# -1

[string]::Compare('z','~',[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture,[System.Globalization.CompareOptions]::Ordinal)  
# -4

[string]::Compare('~','z',[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture,[System.Globalization.CompareOptions]::Ordinal)  
# 4
```

Comment: I can understand the usefulness of word sort, but I take issue with the idea of using it as the *default comparison collation* for a programming language!

Answer (score 6):

It's because `~` (tilde) is a diacritical mark, and the default comparison is *linguistic* comparison, not ordinal.  Linguistic comparisons ignore diacritical marks when sorting.  It's all a consequence of everything being in Unicode.

Try:

```
PS C:\> $x = @('aaa','~~~','zzz')
PS C:\> [System.Array]::Sort($x)
PS C:\> $x
~~~
aaa
zzz
PS C:\> [System.Array]::Sort($x,[System.StringComparer]::Ordinal)
PS C:\> $x
aaa
zzz
~~~
```

Similar answer in C# is [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/887020/csharp-net-tilde-ascii-sorting-a-string).

Here's a larger comparison using the `en-US` culture with some strings that have diacritical marks:

```
PS C:\> $x = @("0","9","a","A","á","Á","ab","aB","Ab","áb","Áb","Æ","z","Z","~")
PS C:\> [Array]::Sort($x)
PS C:\> $x
~
0
9
a
A
á
Á
ab
aB
Ab
áb
Áb
Æ
z
Z
PS C:\> [Array]::Sort($x,[StringComparer]::Ordinal)
PS C:\> $x
0
9
A
Ab
Z
a
aB
ab
z
~
Á
Áb
Æ
á
áb
```

So, which is correct?  It's going to depend on your application, but the .Net Framework defaults to culture-based comparison.

As far as I'm aware, string comparison defaults to `[System.StringComparer]::CurrentCulture` for case sensitive and `[System.StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` for case insensitive.  I don't know any way to change this directly.  Even using invariant culture doesn't seem to affect things:

```
PS C:\> [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
PS C:\> [System.Array]::Sort($x)
PS C:\> $x
~~~
aaa
zzz
PS C:\> $x[0] -le $x[1]
True
```

To force ordinal comparison, [use System.String.CompareOrdinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af26w0wa(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[System.String]::CompareOrdinal($StringA,$StringB)
```

If the result is negative, then `$StringA` is less than `$StringB`.
If the result is zero, then `$StringA` equals `$StringB`.
If the result is positve, then `$StringA` is greater than `$StringB`.

Thus, this:

```
'zzz' -le '~~~'
```

Is equivalent with ordinal comparisons to:

```
PS C:\> [System.String]::CompareOrdinal('zzz','~~~') -le 0
True
```

Comment: I'm able to work around it -- my only purpose was to have a default stopping point, overridable in a parameter, that was at the end of the list. But this behavior sure was a surprise.

Comment: @RossPresser  See my update.  You can use `String.CompareOrdinal` to force ordinal comparison of strings.