# Strange sorting for character + and /

Tags: java, .net

We've a customer that is asking us to sort some strings this way (for compatibility with an old tool) :

```
  A IR / 
  A IR +100bp 
  B IR / 
  B IR +100bp
```

As you can see the '/' and the '+' are inverted, the standard order is the other way around

```
  A IR +100bp 
  A IR / 
  B IR +100bp 
  B IR /
```

Both characteres are part of the low ASCII table, so amazingly stable.

Anybody has an idea from what language or algo the first order is coming from ( I guess is not the last surprise) ?

Comment: How is this a .net / Java related question?

Comment: we're developing in Java, the old tools was .NET. It's an algo ...maybe

Comment: So then the first order comes from .net...

Comment: *descending* order?

Comment: same for both ....

Comment: Can you try and debug the code with more inputs? Only those 2 characters are switched?

Comment: sorry, not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: because it uses [`[String]::Compare()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_) and that returns the same result [<sup>Thanks briantist</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490661/3439404):

```
[String]::Compare('/','+')
# -1
# Less than zero: `strA` precedes `strB` in the sort order
```

The longer answer is: it's not an `ASCII`/`Unicode codepoint` *ordinal value comparison* but **Unicode string comparison** defined in the [*Unicode Collation Algorithm* report](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

The latter document points to the [Default Unicode Collation Element Table](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#File_Format) as provided in [Allkeys](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/latest/allkeys.txt). This table provides a mapping from characters to collation elements for all the explicitly weighted characters:

> ```
> 002B  ; [*063F.0020.0002] # PLUS SIGN
> 002F  ; [*03A1.0020.0002] # SOLIDUS
> ```

The following (IMHO interesting) example is written in (*`.NET`-based*) Powershell as I don't speak `Java`:

```
( '+-/*+−÷×' | 
    Get-CharInfo | 
        Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | 
            Out-String
).Split( [System.Environment]::NewLine,
         [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries ) |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } |
        Sort-Object -Unique
```

Result:

> ```
> - U+002D     DashPunctuation Hyphen-Minus
> − U+2212          MathSymbol Minus Sign
> * U+002A    OtherPunctuation Asterisk
> / U+002F    OtherPunctuation Solidus
> + U+002B          MathSymbol Plus Sign
> × U+00D7          MathSymbol Multiplication Sign
> ÷ U+00F7          MathSymbol Division Sign
> ```

For the sake of completeness, the `Get-CharInfo` function is defined as follows:

```
<#
_get-CharInfo_1.1.ps1

Origin   by: http://poshcode.org/5234
             sorry, the above link is not available; last time checked 2018-05-07
Improved by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz

Use this like this: "ábč",([char]'x'),0xBF | Get-CharInfo

Activate dot-sourced like this (apply a real path instead of .\):

. .\_get-CharInfo_1.1.ps1
#>

Add-Type -Name UName -Namespace Microsofts.CharMap -MemberDefinition $(
    switch ("$([System.Environment]::SystemDirectory -replace 
                '\\', '\\')\\getuname.dll") {
    {Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf} {@"
[DllImport("${_}", ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int GetUName(ushort wCharCode, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder buf);

public static string Get(char ch) {
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(300);
    UName.GetUName(ch, sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
"@
    }
    default {'public static string Get(char ch) { return "???"; }'}
    })

function Get-CharInfo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject],[System.Array])]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $InputObject
    )
    begin {
        Set-StrictMode -Version latest
        function out {
            param(
                [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true )] $ch,
                [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]$nil=''
                 )
            if (0 -le $ch -and 0xFFFF -ge $ch) {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Char = [char]$ch
                    CodePoint = 'U+{0:X4}' -f $ch
                    Category = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($ch)
                    Description = [Microsofts.CharMap.UName]::Get($ch)
                }
            } elseif (0 -le $ch -and 0x10FFFF -ge $ch) {
                $s = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32($ch)
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Char = $s
                    CodePoint = 'U+{0:X}' -f $ch
                    Category = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($s, 0)
                    Description = '???' + $nil
                }
            } else {
                Write-Warning ('Character U+{0:X} is out of range' -f $ch)
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        if ($PSBoundParameters['Verbose']) {
            Write-Warning "InputObject type = $($InputObject.GetType().Name)"}
        if ($null -cne ($InputObject -as [char])) {
            #Write-Verbose "A $([char]$InputObject) InputObject character"
            out $([int][char]$InputObject) ''
        } elseif ($InputObject -isnot [string] -and $null -cne ($InputObject -as [int])) {
            #Write-Verbose "B $InputObject InputObject"
            out $([int]$InputObject) ''
        } else {
            $InputObject = [string]$InputObject
            #Write-Verbose "C $InputObject InputObject.Length $($InputObject.Length)"
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $InputObject.Length; ++$i) {
                if (  [char]::IsHighSurrogate($InputObject[$i]) -and 
                      (1+$i) -lt $InputObject.Length -and 
                      [char]::IsLowSurrogate($InputObject[$i+1])) {
                    $aux = ' 0x{0:x4},0x{1:x4}' -f [int]$InputObject[$i], 
                                                   [int]$InputObject[$i+1]
                    Write-Verbose "surrogate pair $aux at position $i" 
                    out $([char]::ConvertToUtf32($InputObject[$i], $InputObject[1+$i])) $aux
                    $i++
                } else {
                    out $([int][char]$InputObject[$i]) ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this what it. They we sorting using .NET InvariantCulture , english in Java